# jQuery Waypoints with different actions

Tags: jquery-waypoints

I'm currently using jQuery Waypoints to highlight nav items as you scroll through sections of the page. All of that works fine; thanks to copying the code from the demo at http://imakewebthings.github.com/jquery-waypoints/.

My demo is: http://www.pandlmedia.com/index.php/index_new

However, I also want to create a waypoint at the #footer div which would trigger an event to change the color of all of the nav links.

```
$('#footer').bind('waypoint.reached', function(event, direction) {
    $('.nav ul a').addClass('white');
});
```

This doesn't work, as there's nothing telling it to change back once it exits the #footer div. I'm not very experienced in writing jQuery or using this plug-in for that matter. What do I need to add to make this work? Is the fact that there are two levels of waypoints also causing problems?

Answer (score 0):

well, looking closer at the "sticky elements" demo, I was able to modify the example of the disappearing '.top' button to make this work for my own needs described above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container .nav ul a').addClass('black');
    $.waypoints.settings.scrollThrottle = 30;
    $('#footer').waypoint(function(event, direction) {
        $('.container .nav ul a').toggleClass('black', direction === "up");
    }, {
        offset: '50%'
    });
});
```

The key was to add the .black class below the .white class in my css so that it overrides the color parameter properly.